# How can I list all files except files of extensions [ jpg , png , mkv , etc]? [ BASH wildcards]

Tags: bash

I can list files with above extensions by

```
ls *[m,j,p][n,k,p][v,g]
```

But I want to list all files **except these filetypes**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use grep like this:

```
$ ls | grep -v '[\.jpg$|\.png$|\.mkv$]'
```

The `grep` command, filters out text that match provided regular expression. If `-v` flag is used, then it filters out text that **do not match** provided regular expression (reverse).